# How to calculate delta time (hour) between two datetime from two csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have two csv files, first one (e.g. "time.csv") contains information about ID and specific time (one ID one datetime information).

```
ID     datetime
1      2019-05-01 14:00
2      2019-05-02 12:00
3      2019-04-02 10:00
```

And the other csv file contains other features from each ID with one hour timestamp. One cow may have several rows, and I need to create new columns 'deltahour' which shows the difference between current time and the datetime for specific ID on "time.csv".

```
ID     datetime              deltahour
1      2019-05-01 08:00        6
1      2019-05-01 09:00        5
1      2019-05-01 10:00        4
.
.
1      2019-05-01 14:00        0
2      2019-05-02 08:00        4
2      2019-05-02 09:00        3
.
.
2      2019-05-01 12:00        0
```

How do I get this using Pandas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `merge` then just subtract the value

```
df1.datetime=pd.to_datetime(df1.datetime)
df2.datetime=pd.to_datetime(df2.datetime)

df=df1.merge(df2,on='ID').assign(deltahour=lambda x : x['datetime_x']-x['datetime_y'])
```

Comment: Why do I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'?

Answer (score 0):

## Try using pd.merge after making sure the datetime column is parsed as date

[image]